# What are the pros and cons of having a 'manager' do something with an object or having object doing something itself?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've been exploring the convenience of adding functionality to objects that previously would be handled by 'managers' or 'controllers'. I was just worried if there were any issues working this way. The main issue I can see is coupling.

As an example, lets use firing an employee from a business.

Previously I would work like this:

```
class Employee
{
    // Does employee stuff
}

class Business
{
    public List<Employee> employees
}

class BusinessManagement
{
    Business buisness
    public void FireEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        business.employees.Remove(employee);
    }
}
```

Now I have been trying this:

```
class Employee
{
    Business business
    Fire()
    {
        business.employees.Remove(this);
    }
}

class Business
{
    public List<Employee> employees
}
```

The latter method is nice and convenient because you just need a reference to the employee and you can fire it wherever you like. You also don't need the management class.

Comment: It's difficult to distill from your description what patterns and for what purposes you are going to use. But `business.employees.Remove(...);` is definitely code smell so  both pieces don't look good.

Comment: `class RogueEmployee : Employee { override void Fire() { /*Do nothing*/ } }`. Do you want instances of `Employee` to be able to *control* the firing process?

Comment: Take a look at rich data model vs anemic data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're right to worry about avoiding coupling here – I would consider your example to be bad practice. But let's unpack, and show a way that we can achieve the same behaviour with a contract between the classes that is more comprehensible, predictable and maintainable.

A business has many employees, it knows who it employs - so it makes sense for it to own a collection of references to `Employee` objects. An employee (for the sake of simplicity) works for one business, so it makes sense for an `Employee` to contain a reference to a `Business` object. These references do not necessarily couple the classes together in a negative sense, so long as the contracts between them are clearly in public methods on each object whose invocation is controlled by that class, and whose business logic is the concern of that class.

A business fires an employee, and an employee also needs to know that they are fired. If I was going to do this, I would put the `Fire(Employee e)` method on the `Business` class -  inside this method, I would most likely want to call `e.GetFired()` then remove the employee from the collection of employees. Then,  `Employee.GetFired()` would set the `Employee`'s own `Business` property to null.

This can work in both directions while maintaining the separation between these classes. An employee, presumably, can quit their job - Thus, `Employee.Quit()` can call `Business.EmployeeHasQuit(Employee e)`, passing itself in as a reference - allowing the `Business` instance to take responsibility itself for removing the `Employee` instance from the collection.

Your example is an example of coupling because the Employee class' `GetFired()` method used it's reference to a Business object to access a public collection and delete itself. It would also be coupling if the `Business.Fire(Employee e)` method set `e.Business = null`. It's a reasonable rule of thumb that classes should not directly modify the members of other classes; by letting each class manage its own state, you can implement behaviours to ensure things are always in a valid state, and to trigger other necessary behaviours (e.g. we want to make sure that when an Employee quits, their security pass is revoked, and this would happen inside `EmployeeHasQuit()` – if the employee just deleted itself from the Business' collection, this wouldn't be the case. A business might also want the opportunity to put an employee who has quit or been fired into a formerEmployees collection, to keep track of them later.

Hopefully this serves as an easily digestible example of the ways in which objects can communicate with each other while maintaining full responsibility for their own states and behaviours!

Comment: It has helped me to understand object responsibilities. Look Aggregates and Entities. As @toadfish explained, you can have many possible solutions and I agree that avoiding coupling is the main point. 

If you read about DDD, it will tell that choose the main class (Aggregate) that will hold references to one domain entities. When you handle/manage things, always use the aggregate to access child objects.

For example, `Business` could be the main class that has a reference to Employee. Then `Fire()` is inside Business.